# How do I get rid of this search validation error message?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a search form on my school site, where admins and staff can search for students per class and section.

But I keep getting this error message when I want to submit the form to get students' list from a class and section. I don't know what it means and how to get rid of it.

```
{"status":1,"error":"","params":{"srch_type":null,"class_id":"8","section_id":"1"}}
```

controller code:

```
public function searchvalidation()
    {
        $class_id   = $this->input->post('class_id');
        $section_id = $this->input->post('section_id');

        $srch_type = $this->input->post('search_type');

        if ($srch_type == 'search_filter') {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('class_id', $this->lang->line('class'), 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

                $params = array('srch_type' => $srch_type, 'class_id' => $class_id, 'section_id' => $section_id);
                $array  = array('status' => 1, 'error' => '', 'params' => $params);
                echo json_encode($array);

            } else {

                $error             = array();
                $error['class_id'] = form_error('class_id');
                $array             = array('status' => 0, 'error' => $error);
                echo json_encode($array);
            }
        } else {
            $params = array('srch_type' => 'search_full', 'class_id' => $class_id, 'section_id' => $section_id);
            $array  = array('status' => 1, 'error' => '', 'params' => $params);
            echo json_encode($array);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What error? All you've posted is a custom json response with an empty "error" property. We have _no idea_ what you expect it to return or what is wrong with it. We also have no clue what any of the inputs are, which makes it even more impossible to spot what the issue with the response you get is.

Comment: What debugging have you done, then?? Looks like it doesn't mean much, it's essentially just a dump of some variables, almost certainly generated by this code `$params = array('srch_type' => $srch_type, 'class_id' => $class_id, 'section_id' => $section_id);
                $array  = array('status' => 1, 'error' => '', 'params' => $params);
                echo json_encode($array);` inside `if ($this->form_validation->run() == true`, so probably the outcome is that whatever validation routine you're running succeeded.